# slideDown-callback firing before slideDown is visible in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, prompt

I am building a PhoneGap-App for Android phones. I use a mechanism like this to let the user submit data to a web service:

```
$('#backdrop').slideDown('fast',function(){
  var data = prompt('Please enter your data');
  if (data){
    //process data
  } else {
   //go on
  }
});
```

Yet, when testing this on my phone the prompt will sometimes (in about 80% of the cases I'd guess) be shown *before* the `$('#backdrop')` element is actually visible and wait for the element to be displayed until the prompt is gone (due to its blocking nature).

I have the feeling that this might be due to my really old and slow phone (HTC Wildfire S with 600MHz), yet I am probably not the only one out there with an old and slow phone, so it would be nice to know if there is a way to fix this.

Can I actually fix this by jQuery-means or would that mean that I cannot use the standard prompt and would have to build something on my own (is it a good idea to use `prompt`s at all)? Or is this something completely different that I am not aware of right now?

jQuery version is 1.7.1, Phonegap/Cordova version is 1.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks right. The confirm should wait until the slide animation is complete, then show up.

But i guess what happens is that animation rendering is so bad, the `slideUp` function is complete but not yet visible to user. And then `confirm` comes up and stops the execution.

Javascript animations are known to be terrible on mobile devices and discouraged. Especially in older devices they are unbearable. You may try using CSS3 animations instead. There's a jQuery plugin called [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), which has the same syntax with jQuery's `animate` function but uses CSS3 for animations.

Another advice: If you are using Phonegap, you might prefer `navigator.notification.confirm` instead of old-plain `confirm`, because it uses device's native confirm dialog(better user experience) and it's non-blocking.

Comment: That's exactly what I think is happening. I'll check out the plugin, looks perfect at first glance. I guess I have to use the prompt as confirm won't let get data from the user. Thanks

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, you're right about prompt. Phonegap doesn't have a native prompt function right now. I misread your question.